# Overload dictionary subscript two times and forward call

Tags: swift, overloading

I'm trying to extend `Dictionary` and allow extracting values casted to a certain types and with a given default value. For this I added two overloads for the `subscript` function, one with a default value, one without:

```swift
extension Dictionary {

    subscript<T>(_ key: Key, as type: T.Type, defaultValue: T?) -> T? {
        // the actual function is more complex than this :)
        return nil
    }

    subscript<T>(_ key: Key, as type: T.Type) -> T? {
        // the following line errors out:
        // Extraneous argument label 'defaultValue:' in subscript
        return self[key, as: type, defaultValue: nil]
    }
}
```

However when calling the three-argument subscript from the two-argument one I get the following error:

> Extraneous argument label 'defaultValue:' in subscript

[image]

Is this a Swift limitation? Or am I missing something?

I'm using Xcode 10.2 beta 2.

P.S. I know there are other alternatives to this, like dedicated functions or nil coalescing, trying to understand what went wrong in this particular situation.

Comment: Subscript argument labels don't default to the parameter name, so you need to define the first subscript as `subscript<T>(_ key: Key, as type: T.Type, defaultValue defaultValue: T?)`

Comment: Wow, such a simple fix, thanks @Hamish. Can you add an answer with this? Or should we consider this question as a typo one? :)

Comment: I thought there was a dupe for this, but I can't seem to find it. I guess I might as well write an answer then, as the behaviour isn't exactly obvious :)

Comment: Yeah, myself also searched for a similar question before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subscripts have different rules than functions when it comes to argument labels. With functions, argument labels default to the parameter name – for example if you define:

```
func foo(x: Int) {}
```

you would call it as `foo(x: 0)`.

However for subscripts, parameters don't have argument labels by default. Therefore if you define:

```
subscript(x: Int) -> X { ... }
```

you would call it as `foo[0]` rather than `foo[x: 0]`.

Therefore in your example with the subscript:

```
subscript<T>(_ key: Key, as type: T.Type, defaultValue: T?) -> T? {
    // the actual function is more complex than this :)
    return nil
}
```

The `defaultValue:` parameter has no argument label, meaning that the subscript would have to be called as `self[key, as: type, nil]`. In order to add the argument label, you need to specify it twice:

```
subscript<T>(key: Key, as type: T.Type, defaultValue defaultValue: T?) -> T? {
    // the actual function is more complex than this :)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html) doesn't mention this and in fact gives an example of the usage of `subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Double`.

Comment: @trojanfoe It's documented here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_subscript-declaration – "*By default, the parameters used in subscripting don’t have argument labels, unlike functions, methods, and initializers. However, you can provide explicit argument labels using the same syntax that functions, methods, and initializers use.*"

Comment: @trojanfoe I document it here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_subscripts As I say there, I regard the exceptionalism of the subscript external argument name rules as a bug in the language.

Comment: @matt Yeah it's a bit confusing.  Still not sure how the example given in the documentation I linked works without argument labels.

Comment: @matt I wouldn’t call it a bug per se, though the design decision is certainly questionable.

Comment: @trojanfoe The example of `subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Double` is called using the syntax of `matrix[0, 1] = 1.5` in the documentation, which is consistent with how subscript argument labels work (i.e there's no argument label because it wasn't stated explicitly).

Comment: @Hamish Ah I understand; it's how they are used when calling the subscript, not implementing it.