# Can a protocol define subscript(keyPath:) without an explicit implementation in the adopting object?

Tags: swift, protocols, keypaths

Since Swift 4, objects have gained `subscript(keyPath:)` which can be used to retrieve values using `AnyKeyPath` and its subclasses. According to [the Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html), the subscript `is available on all types`. For example, an instance of a class `TestClass` may be subscripted with an `AnyKeyPath` like so:

```swift
class TestClass {
    let property = true
}

let anyKeyPath = \TestClass.property as AnyKeyPath
_ = TestClass()[keyPath: anyKeyPath]
```

This compiles correctly as expected. Use of any other valid subclass would also compile including `PartialKeyPath<TestClass>`, `KeyPath<TestClass, Bool>`, etc. This functionality is unavailable in a protocol extension. For example, the following is invalid:

```swift
class TestClass {
    let property = true
}

protocol KeyPathSubscriptable {

}

extension KeyPathSubscriptable {
    func test() {
        let anyKeyPath = \TestClass.property as AnyKeyPath
        _ = self[keyPath: anyKeyPath] // Value of type 'Self' has no subscripts
    }
}
```

If we want to use that keyPath subscript in the protocol, we can include it in the protocol definition. However, the compiler will not resolve it automatically:

```swift
protocol KeyPathSubscriptable {
    subscript(keyPath: AnyKeyPath) -> Any? { get }
}

extension KeyPathSubscriptable {
    func test() {
        let anyKeyPath = \TestClass.property as AnyKeyPath // This can be any valid KeyPath
        _ = self[keyPath: anyKeyPath]
    }
}

class TestClass: KeyPathSubscriptable { // Type 'TestObject' does not conform to protocol 'KeyPathSubscriptable'
    let property = true
}
```

With this, we get a compile error: `Type 'TestObject' does not conform to protocol 'KeyPathSubscriptable'`. In order to resolve this, we must include a redundant implementation of that subscript in `TestClass`:

```swift
class TestClass: KeyPathSubscriptable {
    let property = true

    subscript(keyPath: AnyKeyPath) -> Any? {
        fatalError() // This is never executed
    }
}
```

This resolves the conformance issue and produces the goal result although it is seemingly unnecessary and illogical. I'm not sure how, but the subscript implementation is never even used. It's finding the expected implementation of `subscript(keyPath:)` and using that instead, but how? Where is that and is there any way to use it in a protocol? Why is this required by the compiler even though it's never used?

The context of this use case is in a logging module. The goal is that an object should be able to adopt a particular protocol which, with no additional setup on the object, would provide a human readable `description` of the object, instead of the default for many objects which is a memory address. The protocol would use Mirror to fetch `KeyPath`s of an object, read the values, and print them to the console. It is intended for debugging purposes and would not run in any production environment.

Please let me know if I can make any clarifications. I may post this to the Swift team if others think that this could potentially be a bug of sorts. All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Full gist located [here](https://gist.github.com/mtfourre/744c42b8c4ef28558202089f23c6fc7d).

Comment: Why use keypaths here? Isn't this exactly what Mirror.children is for?

Comment: @RobNapier This is mostly experimental. Mirror.children provides a solution as you said. As far as this post is concerned though, the questions are about the behavior of key paths, not about a solution for the logging module.

Comment: OK, in that case I'd open this as a Swift defect at bugs.swift.org. Definitely Swift shouldn't behave this way (most significantly the fact that the custom subscript code is never called; that *can't* be right).

Comment: I thought the same. Thanks for your time and your feedback @RobNapier it is much appreciated.

Comment: But as written, your code can't really be useful, since `\TestClass.property as AnyKeyPath` is going to fail for everything but TestClass. (It'll return nil when you try to use it). It's correct that it compiles; it just can't return anything useful.

Comment: You are correct. The implementation was simplified (to the point of being useless) in the interest of keeping the question from getting too long. In order to avoid too many back and forth comments here, I will update the gist with a full example implementation to show optimal context.

Comment: Your second example compiles for me in both Xcode 11 beta 4 and on master. For your gist you're missing the argument label from the subscript, it should be `subscript(keyPath keyPath: AnyKeyPath) -> Any?` for both the protocol requirement and implementation – once changed, the fatal error is hit as expected. The compiler should prefer a user-defined `keyPath:` subscript over the implicitly defined one provided by the compiler.

Comment: How obnoxious. I wouldn't have even known that there was a difference between `subscript(keyPath: AnyKeyPath) -> Any?` and `subscript(keyPath keyPath: AnyKeyPath) -> Any?` let alone that the implicitly defined version was implemented like the latter. I believe that this is the cause of the confusion. @Hamish could you help me understand why `keyPath: AnyKeyPath` isn't the same as `keyPath keyPath: AnyKeyPath`? They are invoked in the same way. I thought the label was implied when left empty. I can make another question if necessary.

Comment: @MichaelFourre Subscripts argument labels are an unfortunate inconsistency in the language, you have to specify them explicitly along with the parameter name, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54710425/2976878.